# Is there any way to add a timeout to polars.read_database?

Tags: python, python-polars

I'm periodically selecting data (using `polars.read_database` with a connection uri) from a Postgres materialized view that eventually becomes unreachable during refreshes.

Is there anything to be done to avoid waiting indefinitely for an answer from the server?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try using the command timeout parameter in your connection string https://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html